# how i install gcc to my new linux system by using source code :centos5.2?

Tags: linux, gcc

In my new centos5.2 system, there are not any component.

if using Source code installing method, failled! because there is  not a compiler for c/c++ code.

how to use rpm method? which  dependencies  i need?

thanks!
Michael zhou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
yum install gcc gcc-c++ kernel-devel
```